# How insert java data generation function into PostgreSQL table?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have PostgreSQL db and I use JDBC to connect and generate table, but I want to generate table with random data. so I create java methods which generate random names and surnames which I want to set into my table into special columns (name, surname).
My db :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups;
CREATE TABLE groups(
name VARCHAR(50),
surname VARCHAR(50),
);
```

and I try to set name and surname using this code:

```
    String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school";
    String user = "principal";
    String password = "123";

    String sqlScript = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("src/main/resources/database/dbScript.sql")));

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password);
    System.out.println("Success.........");
    Statement script = connection.createStatement();
    script.execute(sqlScript);
    //class with random gen.
    StudentsGenerator generator = new StudentsGenerator();
    
    String query1 = "INSERT INTO groups " +"VALUES (generator.student().stream().map(names -> names.getName()))";
    script.executeUpdate(query1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the syntax of `INSERT` statement with multiple values is allowed:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1, col2) VALUES 
('val11', 'val12'),
('val21', 'val22'),
...
('valN1', 'valN2');
```

such statement can be generated:

```java
String manyInserts = "INSERT INTO groups VALUES " 
    + students.stream()
              .map(student -> String.format("('%s', '%s')", student.getName(), student.getSurname()))
              .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
script.executeUpdate(manyInserts);
```

However, this approach is not protected from SQL injections and it is more preferable to use batch inserts for `PreparedStatement`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO groups (name, surname) VALUES (?, ?)");
students.forEach(student -> {
    ps.setString(1, student.getName());
    ps.setString(2, student.getSurname());
    ps.addBatch();
});
ps.executeBatch();
```